# When softDeletes() is use with the parent, what is the best way to handle all of its child

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a table for publications, which has a relationship of one-to-many with the table reviews, each publication has many reviews.

I'm using AngularJS for the frontend and Laravel for the backend and MySQL for the database.

Let's say I would `softDeletes()` one of the publication, should I also need to use `softDeletes()` to all of its reviews? When `softDeletes()` is used with the parent, what is the best way to handle all of its child

Currently this is the solutions that I can think of base on my research but I still have doubts to what is the best way regarding of performance :

```
1. Only update the deleted_at column in publications table and leave 
   the reviews table as it is.

2. Create a MySQL trigger to update the deleted_at column in reviews 
   table when user softDeletes() the publication.

3. Update deleted_at column in table reviews inside laravel controller, 
   which will use foreach. But I think this has a performance issue assuming 
   that the publication have hundreds or thousands of reviews.

4. Create a different table for reviews which parent is temporarily inactive. 
   Separating reviews that are active and inactive, I think this will help in 
   query performance. I'm not sure.
```

Sorry if some of my grammar is wrong but if you understand my question I would be happy to hear your thoughts. Thank you.

Comment: I'd add event listeners to the model for the `deleted` and `restored` events. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events

Comment: Oh, yeah Events, I forgot to include it. I can watch publications and if its deleted I can then trigger foreach to update its child, but I would like to avoid foreach in my laravel. Is there any way like `UPDATE ON CASCADE`?

Comment: No need to foreach. `$model->children()->update(['deleted_at', $model->deleted_at]);` should do the trick.

Comment: Great! Let me try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to do anything at all?

If you can't access single reviews without going through the parent->child relationship, there's no real reason to do anything with the reviews.

If you can access single reviews, just add a constraint to not fetch reviews where the parent is `softdeleted()`

But if you don't like that approach, just enable softdeletes on your reviews and when you `destroy()` a publication:

```
foreach($publication->reviews as $review) {
    $review->delete();
}
```

Comment: `Do you need to do anything at all?` I would like to do the solution #1, but I'm having doubts about the performance of query if the, let say hundreds reviews are still in the table. i'll update my question, I forgot something to include.

Comment: My point is, if the reviews are inherently tied to publications (meaning you can't access a review without first going through the publication), there's no real need to do anything with the reviews. Once you `restore()` the publication, the reviews are sitting there nice and snug waiting for it.

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. I updated my question with additional solution, but I'm not sure, If I will not remove all the inactive reviews in the table can query performance be affected?

Comment: If it does, I imagine it would be so negligible it won't matter. It won't be an issue on the database side, as MYSQL doesn't "recognize" soft deleted records as being soft deleted. That's a "laravel thing". When a model has soft deletion enabled, any query made on that model will automatically disregard soft deleted records. To get those, you need to use the `withTrashed()` method.

Comment: What I mean is, for example you have a thousands of reviews and hundreds of it is inactive. If i'm not wrong the query will still search the table including the active and inactive. It's still consumes time at the database before returning to laravel right? or I just didn't understand the concept.

Comment: I think you're right, Since publication is not in the list the user will have no access to all of its reviews. Thank you.

Comment: If you've added foreign keys to the parent->child relationship, this will help with performance btw. But modern databases are fast. Very fast. Unless you're looking at a massive scale database (millions of records), the performance gain may be negligible, but it can be useful nonetheless.

Comment: Yeah, I have the publication id referenced in my reviews table.

Comment: Yup. Done, I have a working database now. I just got stuck with this issue, anyway I made up my mind to what method should I use. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's Eloquent [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events) are likely the best bet here.

```
Model::deleted(function ($model) {
    $model->children()->update(['deleted_at', $model->deleted_at]);
});

Model::restored(function ($model) {
    $model->children()->update(['deleted_at', null]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try that.